# paypal get notified about payment without IPN on other peoples accound

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am building a small marketplace for custom made products.
The sellers will register, enter they paypal address then
list their products for sale.

When a visitor decides to buy a product. The user will
be redirected to Paypal and the payment will be sent to
seller's PayPal address. I don't want to make users
to enable IPN, not to confuse them. Also there is no
way I can check whether a client as successfully enabled
IPN or not. So it is not an option for me.

So is there any way my website can be notified after
a successful payment that was sent to seller's paypal?

1 Client Selects Product764 of Seller Bobby192
2 Paypal form sends the money to Bobby192 paypal.
3 Client completes the payment
4 Paypal sends payment confirmation back to my website without IPN.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with PayPal's Adaptive Payments APIs. A highlevel overview of the options can be found here:

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/

Comment: Oh don't thank me. You are entering a world of paypal API pain. :)

Comment: I have experienced IPN pain so I guess I got used to it. I love stripe api however thanks again :)